# My code is compiled into errors saying db.collection is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
// import database from 'firebase/database';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
```

firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

```
function Sidebar() {    
    const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const analytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
    // // const db = getFirestore(FirebaseApp);
    // // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
    
    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('rooms').onSnapshot((snapshot) => 
            setRooms (
                snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    data: doc.data(),
                }))
            )
        );
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the new Modular SDK. Try refactoring the code like this:

```
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

useEffecet(() => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "rooms"));
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const rooms = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      rooms.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log(rooms);
  });
}, [])
```

You can learn more about the new syntax for Firestore queries in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9_3).

Comment: unsubscribe is assigned but never used?

Comment: @ChristianNnorom it seems you are never using the unsubscribe function? You can just remove `const unsubscribe = ` this part.

Comment: Thank you very much Dharmaraj. I am still learning how to use javascript , couldnt wrap my head on how the code should be use , so from the documentation I realised my code uses the old version 8.0.1 i simply uninstalled firebase 9.0.1 and installed 8.0.1 with npm install firebase@8.0.1 and it got my code running.   THANKS A LOT

Comment: I would train on the 9.0.1 code thanks